# Blinking of Bootstrap Tabs in some of pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a website where i am facing problem in bootstrap tabs. Bootstrap tabs blinks on some of the pages. here is video of blinking tab in search result page....

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5Y29eu5vYs

and here is same tab on different page where is does not blinks.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qWCgJi_58ws

I have search out problem in all the code but did not find anything. Plz Plz Help me.

Comment: Please go read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As on search page. there is 2 tabs in search page while in other video, there is only one tab. It might be possible that some jQuery code did wrong in search page. See you jQuery code or remove left sidebar on search page and test.

Hope it will work.